# SwiftUI Error: "Closure containing control flow statement cannot be used with function builder 'ViewBuilder'"

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui-foreach

I tried a SwiftUI tutorial, "Handling User Input".

https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/handling-user-input

I tried implementing it with `for` instead of `ForEach`.
But an error arose: "Closure containing control flow statement cannot be used with function builder 'ViewBuilder'".

FROM:

```
import SwiftUI

struct LandmarkList: View {
    @State var showFavoritesOnly = true
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            List{
                Toggle(isOn: $showFavoritesOnly){
                    Text("Show FavatiteOnly")
                }
                
                ForEach(landmarkData) { landmark in
                    if !self.showFavoritesOnly || landmark.isFavorite {
                            NavigationLink(destination: LandmarkDetail(landmark: landmark)) {
                                LandmarkRow(landmark: landmark)
                            }
                        }
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Landmarks"))
        }
    }
}
```

TO (I wrote):

```
import SwiftUI

struct LandmarkList: View {
    @State var showFavoritesOnly = true
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            List{
                Toggle(isOn: $showFavoritesOnly){
                    Text("Show FavatiteOnly")
                }
                
                for landmark in landmarkData {
                    if $showFavoritesOnly || landmark.isFavorite {
                        NavigationLink(destination: LandmarkDetail(landmark: landmark)){
                            LandmarkRow(landmark: landmark)}
                        }
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Landmarks"))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `ForEach` is a special view, but `for` is control flow statement which is not allowed in ViewBuilder where you try to put it in.

Comment: Why do you want to use `for`? The `ForEach` view exists precisely because a regular `for` loop can't be used within a view builder function. But there really isn't anything you could do with a `for` loop that you can't do with `ForEach`, so knowing what you want to achieve would help us answer your question.

Answer (score 19):

The `ForEach` conforms to `View`, so at its core, it is a `View` just like a `TextField`. [ForEach Relationships](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/foreach#relationships)

You can't use a normal `for-in` because the `ViewBuilder` doesn't understand what is an imperative for-loop. The `ViewBuilder` can understand other control flow like `if`, `if-else` or `if let` using [buildEither(first:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/viewbuilder/buildeither(first:)), [buildEither(second:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/viewbuilder/buildeither(second:)), and [buildif(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/viewbuilder/buildif(_:)) respectively.

Answer (score 6):

Try to comment out the if statement, and Xcode might reveal the real error to you. Here's one example: I was getting this error because of a missing associated value of an enum passed to one of my views.

Here's how it looked like before and after:

## Before

```
Group {
    if let value = valueOrNil {
        FooView(
            bar: [
                .baz(arg1: 0, arg2: 3)
            ]
        )
    }
}
```

## After

```
Group {
    if let value = valueOrNil {
        FooView(
            bar: [
                .baz(arg1: 0, arg2: 3, arg3: 6)
            ]
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Add this to the list of non-sensical compiler issues ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ really misled me when I had just added a param in a function. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly my issue with the same error.